# Is there a cleaner way of writing same method with different parameters?

Tags: java, methods, overloading

I need to have multiple methods taking different parameters. Is there a cleaner way of writing those methods instead of declaring each one of them separately? I need 4 the same methods in total. Am I able to write one but let it decide what parameters are passed? Or do I have to end up copying and pasting first one 3 times and changing the parameters. Here are 2 of them

```
public String findLogNumber(XWPFWordExtractor we) {
    int logIndex;
    int logIndexEnd;
    String logNumber = "";
    if (we.getText().contains("Log ")) {
        logIndex = we.getText().indexOf("Log ") + 4;
        logIndexEnd = logIndex + 5;
        logNumber = we.getText().substring(logIndex, logIndexEnd);
    }
    return logNumber;
}

public String findLogNumber(WordExtractor we) {
    int logIndex;
    int logIndexEnd;
    String logNumber = "";
    if (we.getText().contains("Log ")) {
        logIndex = we.getText().indexOf("Log ") + 4;
        logIndexEnd = logIndex + 5;
        logNumber = we.getText().substring(logIndex, logIndexEnd);
    }
    return logNumber;
}
```

Comment: For your example use generics

Comment: Do `WordExtractor` and `XWPFWordExtractor` have a common interface/super class that contains the `getText()` method?

Comment: Aside: rather than using `contains` then `indexOf`, you can use `indexOf` outside the `if`, and check if the returned value is `>= 0`. Just saves doing the same work twice.

Comment: @reporter generics don't help here. Generics only really help when you need to constrain a generic parameter to be related to other parameters (e.g. two lists of the related element types) or you want the parameters and the return value to be related.

Comment: @AndyTurner but the body of both methods are identical. The only one difference is the passed parameter. Finaly Kayaman used the superclass of them as a "generic type". :-)

Comment: @reporter that's not what "generic type" means in Java. That's just a common supertype. As described [in the spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5), a generic type is a type which has type parameters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both `XWPFWordExtractor` and `WordExtractor` extend `org.apache.poi.POITextExtractor` which defines the `getText()` method, so you only need a single method for those that takes `POITextExtractor` as parameter.

```
// Handles at least the two methods shown.
public String findLogNumber(POITextExtractor we) {
    int logIndex;
    int logIndexEnd;
    String logNumber = "";
    if (we.getText().contains("Log ")) {
        logIndex = we.getText().indexOf("Log ") + 4;
        logIndexEnd = logIndex + 5;
        logNumber = we.getText().substring(logIndex, logIndexEnd);
    }
    return logNumber;
}
```

Comment: The very slight difference between this and my answer is that this will accept *any* `POITextExtractor`; mine will only allow you to pass those two specific types. Which of these is preferable entirely depends upon what you're trying to do; but unless you've got a strong reason to disallow some subtypes, this way is easier.

Comment: I'm new to Apache POI. Thank you for this answer! :)

Comment: Yes, Andy's answer is more general (and thus useful), while mine is very specific to this particular case with POI.

Answer (score 4):

Write a method which takes the `we.getText()` as a `String`, and call from the other two methods:

```
public String findLogNumber(XWPFWordExtractor we) {
  return common(we.getText());
}

public String findLogNumber(WordExtractor we) {
  return common(we.getText());
}

private String findLogNumber(String text) {
  // ...
}
```

Unless, of course, `XWPFWordExtractor` and `WordExtractor` implement a common interface or extend the same class. In which case:

```
public String findLogNumber(CommonInterface we) { ... }
```